# Where does the mapStateToProps state comes from?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to React Native and currently maintaining an application built-in ReactNative. In my existing application, we use combineReducers with reduxSause. Based on what I found on the internet, combineReducers will manage a separate state for each reducers (i.e in the below example apple will have separate state and banana will have separate state)

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  a: apples,
  b: bananas
});
```

In Page Screen, I am also using mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. My question is where does the state come from for mapStateToProps? Because when I call the Dispath callback function to appleReducer, state over there is empty.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      const { data } = state.bstate
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      getLine:(input) => dispatch(BType.getLine(input)),
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `connect` function from the `react-redux` library, it is the `connect` function that use `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` and injects state to them:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: Hi @lavor, Thanks, but my question is which state it represents? because when I call the reductor's function, the state in reducer is empty (wherein mapStatetoProps state has some values on it)

Comment: It represents the combined state `{ a: apples, b: bananas}`. Hence, the state argunment of the mapStateToProps should have that combined state object. Can you post code of mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps and code when you using your state and how are you dispatching the action + code of the action itself? Because I do understand the problem from this: "when I call the reductor's function, the state in reducer is empty".

Comment: Hi lavor, Thanks for your reply. I found the solution for this. In the current application somewhere old developer was persisting only B state and also in mapStateToProps I am getting only the B State. When I am calling Apple's reducer function it is empty because we donot persist data here,